# SQLite. How to return 1 and 0 in different columns if specific values occurs

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I am new to SQL and especially SQLite which is expurgated in comparison to sql as I've just learned.

I've got a table which looks like this:

```
id_foo | foo_val
________________
  1    |    3
  1    |    1
  2    |    2
```

I need a query that would give me a table with values 1 and 0 if specific value occured:

```
id_foo | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
_______|______|______|______|______|
  1    |   1  |   0  |  1   |  0   |
  2    |   0  |   1  |  0   |  0   |
```

I've tried to do this with "if exists" command, but "sqliteman" doesn't recognise this command :/

Comment: That kind of output transformation is better done in your client than via a query.

Comment: I use sqliteman only for testing queries which next are embedded in my java code and sent do DB.

Range of values in table is not constant.

Comment: @MarcB: An aggregation is *best done by the RDBMS* in most cases. That's one of the things it is good at. (Not sure about SQLite, but other RDBMS certainly are.) Also, the resulting set is usually smaller by an order of magnitude which can be a treat for slow connections.

Comment: @Erwin: but transforming one column into 4 is better done client-side, unless your rdbms supports pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick:

```
SELECT id_foo
      ,max(CASE WHEN foo_val = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val1
      ,max(CASE WHEN foo_val = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val2
      ,max(CASE WHEN foo_val = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val3
      ,max(CASE WHEN foo_val = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS val4
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id_foo
ORDER  BY id_foo
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite uses 1 and 0 for booleans](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean) so you can do this if you don't like Erwin's CASE:

```
select id_foo,
       max(foo_val = 1) as val1,
       max(foo_val = 2) as val2,
       max(foo_val = 3) as val3,
       max(foo_val = 4) as val4
from pancakes
group by id_foo
order by id_foo
```

But keep in mind that use CASE should work everywhere.